# INSERT To command in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to transfer data between databases, but cannot get INSERT to work.

```
USE [db1_Name]

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[company$Customer]

[No_]      
GO


USE [db2_Name]
GO

SELECT 

[No_]     
FROM [dbo].[company$Customer]

GO
```

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554157/select-into-statement-where-source-is-other-database.

Comment: `insert into [db1_name].[dbo].[company$Customer] select [No_] from [db2_Name].[dbo].[company$Customer]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your script to

```
INSERT INTO DbnameTarget.[dbo].[company$Customer]
SELECT
Colum1,Colum2
FROM DbnameSource.[dbo].[company$Customer]
```

Replace Dbnames,colums with your own

Comment: thank you! unfortunately, at the end of the day this wasn't the command I was looking for! It was actually UPDATE I needed to use. Anyway, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select * into [DestinationDB].dbo.tableName 
  from [SourceDB.dbo].SourceTable
```

(or)
      select * into [Destinationserver].[DestinationDB].dbo.tablename 
      from [Sourceserver].[SourceDB].dbo.tablename